# Cacheable does not cacahe anything when used with REST on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have tried many variations without any luck. It looks like `Cacheable` does not cache anything. The GET request always lasts 5 seconds.

This is my `EventRepository`:

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EventRepository implements Events {

    @Override
    @Cacheable("events")
    public String getEvent(Integer eventId) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        int someNumber = eventId * eventId + eventId;
        return Integer.toString(someNumber);
    }
}
```

This is my `Events`:

```
public interface Events {
    String getEvent(Integer eventId);
}
```

This is my `TestTestApplication`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class TestTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And this is my `EventController`:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class EventController {
    
    public EventRepository eventRepository = new EventRepository();
    
    @GetMapping(value = "events/{eventId}")
    public String getEvent(@PathVariable Integer eventId) throws InterruptedException {
        return this.eventRepository.getEvent(eventId);
    }
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: You are using your own instance of `EventRepository`. Use the bean from the application context!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thank you! Can you write it as answer. It worked. In `EventController` I have changed it to `public final EventRepository eventRepository;`. And also I have created a constructor `public EventController(final EventRepository eventRepository) {this.eventRepository = eventRepository;}`

Comment: I am convinced that there are several questions (and answers) on SO dealing with exactly that topic. So might be better to mark this one as a duplicate instead of answering it.